# no relation between a fact table with date attribute and dim date

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have a cube with several fact tables and a dim date.  The fact tables have date fields but when I try to deploy, deployment fails because there is no relation between the fact table and any dimensions. Also when I check my dimension usage I don't see any relations detected.  I don't understand why the fact table date attributes are not "relating" to the dim date.
When I look within the data source view I see a relationship between the date fields in my fact tables and dim date but no relation in the cube, where should I look to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to check their connection inside the Dimension Usage (2nd tab of a Analysis project). At this point you have to state the relationships between facts and dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

From the solution, double click cubename, then go to dimension usage tab, if you don't see date dimension there, right click somewhere and say add and then follow wizard...